# Input validation in webapp

Tags: web-applications, clojure

What is a recommended approach in clojure to validate request input parameters on server-side?

Is it worth using any validation library for this purpose? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: Is it for client-side or server-side validation?

Comment: @marctrem for server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific enough so in the meantime have a look at these libraries:

https://github.com/Prismatic/schema

http://yogthos.github.io/lib-noir/noir.validation.html

Comment: thanks for answer. Btw why is the question is not specific enough?

Comment: Well, you asked for 'a recommended approach' but didn't tell how you want to validate. So I can't say which one is better for your case

Answer (score 2):

Formative provides client-side and server-side input validation => https://github.com/jkk/formative

Answer (score 1):

The best validation library is: http://bit.ly/1y0UMH8

https://github.com/michaelklishin/validateur

https://github.com/leonardoborges/bouncer